# "syntax error: data truncated" when parsing AppStore Receipts

Tags: go, app-store, asn.1, pkcs#7, der

I am trying decode an asn1 object which follows the following format:

```
ReceiptModule DEFINITIONS ::=
BEGIN
 
ReceiptAttribute ::= SEQUENCE {
    type    INTEGER,
    version INTEGER,
    value   OCTET STRING
}
 
Payload ::= SET OF ReceiptAttribute
 
END
```

as per https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html.

However when I try and decode some samples (some examples can be found [here](https://github.com/veehaitch/devicecheck-appattest/blob/main/src/test/resources/ios-14.4.yaml)), I am consistently getting

```
asn1: syntax error: data truncated
```

here is a reference to the playground I am testing this in: https://go.dev/play/p/K12y0jzwzSQ

When I paste the structure, and receipt into the following online tool: https://asn1.io/asn1playground/ I am able to decode the receipt.

I think I must be mis understanding how this asn1 library works. Hoping someone can help shed some light.

Comment: "The issues" you're having are not stated. Also, you are not checking the errors from `asn1.Unmarshal`.

Comment: And also, from your description, it is not clear, whether `payloaddata` contains the source base64-encoded string or decapsulated DER-encoded data. Please take time to make your question answerable.

Comment: @kostix I have updated the post. Hope this helps.

Comment: OK, it's actionable now. I've tried to debug it a bit but actually if I get the contents of the `Content` field out of the value generated by `pkcs7.Parse` and submit it to `openssl asn1parse -inform DER -parsestr -i`, it fails with an error `Error in encoding
140045447800128:error:0D07209B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:too long:../crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c:91:` while it's fine with decoding the whole source PKCS7-encoded data structure. Looks like a bug in that `pkcs7` package.

Comment: Also, if we take the content from the `openssl asn1parse` on the original source, "undump" it from ASCII HEX encoding (using `xxd -r -p`, for instance), `openssl asn1parse` cannot parse it with the same error, and [this](https://holtstrom.com/michael/tools/asn1decoder.php) fails, too. But your playground appears to cope. I'm really out of ideas now.

Comment: …I mean, it _might_ be some problem with how Apple actually encodes the "content" of the PKCS#7 form of its Receipt: `openssl asn1parse` happily decodes the PKCS#7 container itself but it does not "descend" into the actual contents of it, and when we try to interpret that contents as a DER encoding of some ASN.1 syntax, this fails with some tools but works with others, thus looking like some tools are lax to certain problems with encoding while others are not. Just guessing, though.

Comment: im wondering if instead of using this asn1 library, there is some MVP for implementing the parsing myself since I know the expected structure

Comment: Well, I got interested in this case, so [here we go](https://gist.github.com/kostix/d71582edd6862df19d17135ea99b20b2). I'm not really sure what to do. It appears to me like a bug on the AppStore's side, and you could possibly report it. Please note that my gist has your properties embedded in a base64-encoded form. If they are private, please tell me and I'll remove that part.

Comment: I see, but I am able to decode the object fully using the online parser. I was able to print out and verify the content of the receipts that you decoded. Wondering if it is possible to decode the rest. Will keep playing with this to try and find out. If you see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/assessing_fraud_risk, there should be a risk metric in field 17. I am mainly interested in trying to get to that data. However, with your algorithm was able to get some other data such as field 2 (appID)

Comment: @Iza: I looked at the first example in the file that you linked. I am not able to decode the Payload from that particular receipt using the ASN.1 playground or any of the other ASN.1 tools that I use. I found that there are two extraneous bytes (x04 x4F) at offset 1058. I removed those two bytes and the problem went away.

Comment: I also looked at the second receipt in the page that you linked. In that receipt, there are three extraneous bytes (51 3D 3D) near the end of the payload. When I removed those three bytes, the payload was decoded fine.

Comment: @kostix: Your sample code produces that particular error because you seem to have extracted a fragment that is exactly 1000 bytes long. The encoded payload is longer than that. However, I wonder if there is a particular reason why you extracted exactly 1000 bytes or it is a coincidence, since the two extraneous bytes (x04 x4F) are immediately after the 1000th byte of the payload.

Comment: @Alessandro, I think I got tripped by `openssl asn1parse` only outputting exactly 1000 bytes of the PKCS#7 payload :-( What tool/code have you used to decapsulate the payload?

Comment: @kostix: I did it by hand. I looked at the binary. The tag of the payload is the second 0x31 (SET / SET OF). In the first receipt in the example, the length says 0x433 (1075 decimal), but I noticed that the content spans 1077 bytes because of two extraneous bytes (0x04 0x4F). If you extract just 1075 bytes you will get a truncated content with two extra bytes in the middle.

Comment: @Alessandro, I think we were both wrong but you have put me on the right track ;-) The full output of `openssl asn1parse -inform DER ...` on the OP's PKCS#7 container is [there](https://pastebin.com/wiG5dTFF); if we look at line 13, it lists a _constructed_ object (hence `cons`) with the following two `OCTET STRINGS`—one which I have used initially, of exactly 1000 bytes in length, and another one containing 79 bytes. I have concatenated their decoded forms (obtained by `xxd -r -p`) and run through my decoder—it worked OK…

Comment: …Hence I'm now inclined to think the package used by OP can't grok such "concatenated" forms of `OCTET STRING`s. (To be honest, I did not know they exist.)

Comment: Ugh, the original paste got deleted for some unknown reason. [Here](http://paste.org.ru/?8l2r3f) is another one.

Comment: You are correct. I failed to notice that this was a constructed encoding of an octet string value.

Comment: Hi @Alessandro, @kostix, thanks for taking a look. Having played around with it a bit, I believe you are correct that the issue is with the golang package as opposed to the payload (in particular pkcs7 decryption). Just using the raw receipt with `openssl asn1parse` I am able to decode the receipt.

Comment: Unfortunately your second post was closed. So, what is the asn1 specification of the payload ?